# How do i make my searchbar so that with each word i type it narrows down its search to that specific word

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried finding solutions on the internet, YouTube and even ChatGPT but i can't find anything, been searching for days, any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

Search-filter-pipe :

```
`import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

`@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }
    const searchWords = searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ').filter(word => word.length > 0);

    return items.filter(item => {
      const itemId = String(item.id).toLowerCase();
      return searchWords.every(word => itemId.includes(word));
    });
  }
}
`
```

`app.component.ts` :

```
 click() {
    if (!this.filterTerm || this.filterTerm === '') {
      alert("The input field is empty");
    } else {
      this.productService.search.next(this.filterTerm);
      this.router.navigate(['/product-details', this.filterTerm]);
    }
  }
  
  checkSearch(event: any) {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || !this.filterTerm) {
      this.searchInput = event.target.value;
      this.productService.search.next(this.filterTerm);
      this.router.navigate(['/product-details', this.filterTerm]);
    }
  }
}
```

`app.component.html` :

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto"  id="myNavbar">
                <li class="nav-item nav-link" *ngIf= "router.url!=='/Frontpage'">
                    <div class="search" *ngIf="this.x !== 1">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" (click)="click()" (keydown.enter)="checkSearch($event)"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="searchInput" [(ngModel)]="filterTerm" (keyup)= "checkSearch($event)" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search Games">
                        <ul>
                          <li *ngFor="let product of allProducts | searchFilter: searchText">
                            {{ product.name }}</li>
                        </ul>
                                            
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: This isn't what pipes are for. Search for autocomplete in Angular and you'll find dozens of examples.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that, elaborate

Comment: Pipes are not the right tool for the feature you are building. I just reread and saw you're not looking to build an autocomplete after all. Google will definitely give you solutions though, e.g. https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/creating-a-search-filter-in-angular-562d